# log4net error occurred

Tags: c#, log4net

Below codes make log file Formatted Datetime(e.g.: yyyyMMdd_HHmmss.log)
But there are problems with the results.* * I want to make only one log file When I run the code below * * * * but, two or more log files created.* *
    (e.g.: 20170721_14 * * 22 * * 30.log, 20170721_14 * * 23 * * 00.log, 20170721.....)
i don 't know reason why

i want to solve my problem

How do I fix my code ?

**C# Code:**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{    
    class Program
    {
        static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("DebugLogger");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            for (i=1;i<=50000000;i++)
                Logger.DebugFormat("{0},{1},{2}", 999, 997, 996);
        }
    }
}
```

my **web.config** as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value=""/>
      <datePattern value="yyMMdd_HHmmss'.log '" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <appendToFile value="false" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline">
        </conversionPattern>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="DebugLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: check each of the file size, i believe there is a default file size where when it reach certain size, it will create a new log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected "Date" as the rolling type. So it will separate different logs depending on datePattern:

```
<datePattern value="yyMMdd_HHmmss'.log'" />
```

I believe this will make a new log every SECOND. Since this is the smallest value you specified in your log date pattern.

If you just want one log, then disable rolling!
Or if you want a daily log use:

```
<datePattern value="yyMMdd'.log'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to look at the how to use the configs for log4net. Current config looks like it is used for rolling file appender by date.

If you are not concerned about date, please follow the guide described in log4net's site: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#fileappender